# How to create a css navbar?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm using Django to handle my templates. From the picture I am trying to explain what I want in the web page. For convenience I have given the number for the blocks in the picture. I have created blocks 3,4 5,6, and 7 in one .html file.

I actually want navbar1 and navbar2 to display in every page of my project, and that's why I have to create one separate .html file for each. The problem is that I'm not able to apply two navbars in one html file. I also tried with the sidebar (for navbar2), but have faced some issues.

1. Dropdown button doesn't work on the sidebar and,
2. When I reload the page, the menu of the side bar will display first and then the sidebar will overwrite the menu and then visualize properly.

Please suggest to me how I can design the page for navbar1 and navbar2 in one html file.

[image: .html file view]

Comment: you shoul add your code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `base.html` template that all other templates inherit/extend from should do the trick. Here's a website post going in depth upon how to accomplish this: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/

Comment: yes i knew it ....i actually want code idea for navbar1 and navnar2

Comment: Perhaps rephrase and edit your question/title to instead of implying that you wish to know how to use base templates, to rather ask how to create a navbar. Posting a snippet of your css code will also help us to give you an answer